# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

My entire site runs flawlessly via browser. I have just added a cron job, and each time it runs this error gets triggered:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats))
```

Not sure what is going on. I have logged PHP version both using the browser, and using cron, and it came out the same: 7.3.2-3+0~20190208150725.31+stretch~1.gbp0912bd

What is so different in cron? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 16):

Try altering your `php.ini` file in both `php/[version]/apache2` to resemble this:

```
extension=mysqlnd
extension=mysqli
```

Loading `mysqlnd` first eliminates the error on my debian VM. If you intend to run the same code at the command line, you may wish to consider altering `php/[version]/cli/php.ini` as well.

Answer (score 8):

I have 2 solutions.

Solution one:
I noticed that closing the mysql connection at the end of the script solves the problem.

Solution two:
As it turns out, there was a difference between `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini`.

The first one has this line:

```
    extension=mysqli
```

The second one hat this (note the semicolon):

```
;    extension=mysqli
```

Adding the semicolon to `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` completly fixed my issue.

Comment: i cannot make sense why this works but it works...........when configuring cakephp

Answer (score 3):

comment it out from **/etc/php/[version]/cli/php.ini**:

```
;extension=mysqli
```

leave it as is in **/etc/php/[version]/apache2/php.ini**:

```
extension=mysqli
```

reload apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this by adding a semicolon to each `php.ini` file in `/etc` folder like this.

`;extension=mysqli`

Answer (score -4):

My php version is 7.2

When I run

```
php -m
```

PHP Warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

**SOLUTION**

I just adding the semicolon to `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` completly fixed my issue.